# AAPT: error: unbound prefix. in XML android

Tags: android, xml, data-binding, android-linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:androids="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="titleViewModel"
            type="com.example.screen.title.TitleViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        androids:id="@+id/title_layout"
        androids:layout_width="match_parent"
        androids:layout_height="match_parent"
        androids:gravity="center"
        androids:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".screen.title.TitleFragment">

...more
```

I have an error: unbound prefix at "<LinearLayout...>" line while trying this for data-binding in android app development for the first time.

I have checked other related threads and they said it's about XML namespace, but it seems not the problem here, isn't it?. If not, how to fix it?

Comment: Replace `xmlns:androids="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` with `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: Am I have to change every androids:XXX to android:XXX?

Comment: Yeah it should be `android` not `androids` .

Comment: Thanks! It works, I thought it just something like variables. But, I don't understand if that the case why ```androids``` work without  ```<layout>```  and ```<data>```  tags?

Answer (score 0):

@GottaK
Try to replace <layout xmlns:androids="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" with the below
**<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"**

Comment: Thanks for your comment. By the way, as far as I know, I need the layout tag for data-binding?

and I'm new to the stackoverflow as a user so, how to point ADM comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
# You will have to removed this line
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
        <data>
            <variable
                name="titleViewModel"
                type="com.example.screen.title.TitleViewModel" />
        </data>
<LinearLayout
        androids:id="@+id/title_layout"
        androids:layout_width="match_parent"
        androids:layout_height="match_parent"
        androids:gravity="center"
        androids:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".screen.title.TitleFragment">
```

Comment: Thanks, But Isn't it cause an XML namespace problem with the following tools used at the last line?

Comment: yes but you will use MainLayout like you use given code in LinearLayout or RelativeLayout then you can use xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"